# how do i get my kitten to stop chewing my wires?

Tags: cats, training

I have a 2 month old kitten and she likes to chew/play eith my tv cables and wifi cables. Eveytime she does i say NO! or go snd move her but she just keeps doing it.  Im at my wits end with it. The only room im the house i dont have wires in is my bathroom so for now i have to put her in there when i go out and when i go to bed because i know she will chew through them all when im out or sleeping, i put her food water litter tray and scratcher in the bathroom with her and her bed so she has everything she needs but How do i get her to stop doing it especially when im out or in bed.

Comment: You kitten will be teething, and her permanent teeth will be replacing her deciduous teeth. Get her some chewable toys that she can bite on instead.

Comment: You mention keeping the cat away from wires. But the cat clearly wants to bite _something_. Have you offered it alternatives that it is allowed to bite? (we give our cats cardboard boxes specifically so they leave the cables alone. I much prefer sweeping some cardboard weekly, compared to buying a new cable every day)

Answer (score 1):

Just as your kitten needs a scratcher and toys, she (now and then) needs something to sink her teeth into.

**Part One:**

An alternative, my favourite (and my cats): a cardboard box. Like the one you get from amazon. Cut 2 holes into it, so your little bundle of bounce can get in and out, somewhat easily.

Now, cats (and other animals) don't have same texture detection in their limbs as we humans do. So, the next best thing is your mouth. So there is a good opportunity for your kitten to just taste this cardboard thing of yours.

**Part Two:**

Unlearn. That is a hard thing for cats. Once something is allowed, they will think they can do it always. Unless reinforced to to otherwise.

So, if you say no, (and might need to use a water spray), take your kitten away from the thing she is biting, and put her teeth into the thing you want her to use. Yes, gently push her teeth into the cardboard you want her to use, **gently!**

**Part Three:**

Disable / displease: so your kitten has the habit of knawing on cables. Let's make those cables taste badly. A decent pet store will carry some spray that will help with this. Read instructions carefully.

If that is not available, search for: 'plants cats don't like'. Or, as you can find here: [Make Cat Repellent at Home](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/pests/animals/cat-repellent.htm)

> There are many products on the market to repel cats and help to keep cats out of the yard. For instance, citronella is great to use, as it’s not only safe but also works at repelling other animals too. However, you can make cat repellent at home as well. Home remedies include citrus peels, cayenne, Chile powder, rubbing raw onions on an area, and vinegar.

But use your own judgement, I don't like to use cayenne or hot peppers for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have never had any success distracting my current Little Madam and Boycat from cables she wants to chew, or teaching them not to do it. Instead, I've covered everything accessible with [Critter Cord](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EH2I5O) (other alternatives are available) -- I will not risk them electrocuting themselves by chewing through a power cord.

The protector:

1. Protects the cord from teeth -- flexible, but hard to chew through (even for Boycat who is a rough tough lad with very strong jaws).
2. Smells of citrus, which deters many cats from trying to chew it. (Some people find the smell overpowering, so try just a little to begin with).

This approach has the benefit of working whether you're present or not, and letting you allow the cat safe access to a wider area of the house. Yuu do need to be careful to protect the end of cables as well including plugs -- tuck them away out of reach or (if they'll fit) use a cable management sleeve to cover the ends.